# exiting console application c# and writing to log

Tags: c#, logging, console, exit

So I'm trying to exit a console application IF a parameter check fails, however, I still want it to log to a file.  The logging to a file works fine as long as all the parameters are good.  However, when a parameter check fails and hits the System.Environment.Exit(0) portion, the log file is still completely empty.  Here's the code so far.  Please help, I've tried everything I could think of.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace I2C_File_Splitter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //get command line input paramaters  

            using (StreamWriter log = File.AppendText("Splitter_log.txt"))
            {


                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " ******************************************** SPLITTER STARTED ****************************************************************");
                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " FILE: " + args[0] + " DESTINATION: " + args[1] + " MAX COUNT PER FILE: " + args[2]);


                if (args.Length == 0)
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);


                string originalFile = args[0];

                string destination = args[1];
                int fileLength = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
                string fileName;
                string fileExtension;
                string line;
                int fileNumber = 1;




                if (!File.Exists(originalFile))
                {
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Error: Transfund file not found for: " + args[0]);
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " ******************************************** SPLITTER ENDED ****************************************************************");
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);

                }


                if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
                {
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Error: destination directory not found for: " + args[1] );
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " ******************************************** SPLITTER ENDED ****************************************************************");
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);
                }


                if (fileLength < 0)
                {
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Error: file length must be greater than 0. Incorrect value " + args[2]);
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " ******************************************** SPLITTER ENDED ****************************************************************");
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);
                }


                //get file name and file extension
                fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile);
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(originalFile);



                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(originalFile);

                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " processing: " + fileName); 

                string header = file.ReadLine(); //get first line

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    StreamWriter newFile = new StreamWriter(destination + "\\" + fileName + "_" + fileNumber.ToString() + fileExtension);
                    newFile.WriteLine(header);
                    newFile.WriteLine(line);

                    int counter = 1;
                    while (counter < fileLength)
                    {
                        line = file.ReadLine();

                        if (line == null)
                            break;

                        newFile.WriteLine(line);
                        counter++;

                    }
                    newFile.Close();
                    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + fileName + "_" + fileNumber.ToString() + fileExtension + " created. Card count: " + counter);
                    fileNumber++;
                }

                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Processing completed: " + fileName);
                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " ******************************************** SPLITTER ENDED ****************************************************************");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing a `System.Environment.Exit(0)` instead of just returning out of your Main method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [`Environment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you're telling it to terminate your program immediately.

Your "log" stream never gets flushed (which would happen when you reach the end of the `using` block), and so nothing gets a chance to be written to the file.

Try flushing the stream before calling exit.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
{
    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Error: destination directory not found for: " + args[1] );
    log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " ******************************************** SPLITTER ENDED ****************************************************************");

    // write all pending log messages to the file
    log.Flush();

    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
```